Trying to create an index for a ILIKE query with leading and trailing wildcards, grabbing from a column within a xml data column
I have the following query which is causing performance issues and I am trying to create an index for it:
SELECT inst.policydraftinstanceid, Client.*, 
    COALESCE( ssn, tin ) TaxId
    FROM ypolicydraftinstance inst, XMLTABLE( '/policy-draft-xml/policy/clients/nb-client/roles/role' PASSING policydraftxml COLUMNS 
       name text PATH '../../client/detail/name',
       clientCompositeId text PATH '../../@client-composite-id',
       clientType text PATH '../../client/detail/@type',
       roleType text PATH '@type',
       ssn text PATH '../../client/detail/tax-id/@value',
       tin text PATH '../../client/detail/tax-id/@value',
       dateOfBirth text PATH '../../client/detail/date-of-birth'
       ) Client
     WHERE  Client.Name  ILIKE  '%829116417%' ... more comparisons....

I have tried:
CREATE INDEX test_idx1 ON ypolicydraftinstance USING GIN ( CAST( xpath('/policy-draft-xml/policy/clients/nb-client/client/detail/name/text()', policydraftxml) AS TEXT) gin_trgm_ops ); 

but it will not let me run this query due to xpath not being an immutable function.
Is it safe for me to wrap this with an immutable cast and how would I do it effectively? The name does not frequently get changed but it is possible to change the name, so it is not immutable in the perfect sense of the word. Any other suggestions for performance improvement or different ways of indexing? Thanks.

The only suggestion I can imagine, is to improve your datamodel. Store at least all data that you need for searches, like the name, in an additional column or even table. Create an index on that column and your problem is solved.

xml -> text is immutable, so I don't see any reason xml[] -> text couldn't be as well.  But the automatic cast from array types to text are marked stable, not immutable.  I think this is because some types have casts to text which are mutable, and the system processes this at a level of genericity where it doesn't distinguish the subtypes of the array types. So you could define your own function to do the equivalent of the cast.

The name does not frequently get changed but it is possible to change the name

That isn't what immutable means. Of course the output can change if the input changes.  Immutable means the output cannot change without the input changing (so that it doesn't depend on things like timezone or default_text_search_config)
But it is hard to see how this could work for you anyway as the index and the WHERE test are not over the same expression.

What do you mean by they are not over the same expression? The where expression is using the equivalent xpath from the same table and column, just with the PASSING COLLUMNS syntax.

You may know they are equivalent, but i doubt postgresql knows that.
